# Is there a way to transfer xbox 360 HDD contents to a PC hard drive?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

I'm running out of space on my 360's HDD. There are several installed downloaded games on it.

To clear up space, rather than deleting games (and then later redownloading from Xbox Live when needed), is there a way to just transfer the related files to a PC hard drive for local storage?

Comment: I remember modifying my borderlands saves by moving them a usb, then to a pc. You modify the usb drive to handle xbox files, then need a special program on pc to see them (they would be hidden otherwise on the standard windows explorer). So at the very least getting another hdd or at least a usb drive should be easy to do.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill From the hints in your comment, it looks "FATXplorer" (https://fatxplorer.eaton-works.com/information/) is a program that can do that kind of file backup. I'll test it out later and post as a solution if confirmed working. Thanks.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill From testing, I found out that no extra program was needed. I was able to copy game files (downloaded games from Xbox Live) from the 360 to the USB, and then just plug in that USB to a PC and access the files directly. Being able to do this more easily now might have something to do with one of the 360 firmware updates over the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as downloaded digital games are concerned, one just needs to plug in a USB drive and copy/move the file from the internal HDD of the Xbox 360. 
Then you one just needs plug in that same USB drive to a Windows PC (tested on Win. 7) and just copy and paste the files to the desired backup location.

The formatting was found to be,

```
<USB drive letter>\Content\0000000000000000\<Title ID>,
```

where the Title ID correspond to either the [main games](https://www.gamesdatabase.org/xbox_360_games_list_with_title_ids)
or [XBLA games](https://www.gamesdatabase.org/xbox_live_arcade_games_list_with_title_ids)

As far as games ripped from the disks are concerned, it was not possible to transfer from the 360's HDD to the USB drive.
Its likely that the disk has to rip directly to the USB drive in the first place for this kind of backup to work.